# trying to get info about authenticated user

Tags: javascript, google-authentication, azure-mobile-services

I use Azure Mobile App for Google authentication using the following code:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient(appUrl);
    client.login("google").done(function (results) {
    console.log("You are now logged in as: " + results.userId);                             
}, function (err) {
       console.log("Error: " + err);
    });
```

and it works. But when I try to get info about authenticated user, adding code in done function:

```
var url = client.applicationUrl + '/.auth/me';
fetch(url)
    .then(function (data) {
          return data.json()
     }).then(function (user) {
// The user object contains the claims for the authenticated user
});
```

I get the following error:

> Fetch API cannot load
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=3…
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque
>   response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to
>   fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

This error related to cross-origin request, it can be resolved by two ways:

1. use [jsonp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) instead json, but I don't know how fetch function can work with jsonp.
2. better to use [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), this CORS option should be activated in Google Developer console.

Probably problem is, that my web application and Azure Mobile App are located on different domains, but I added both domains to Authorized JavaScript origins on Google Developer console.

Btw, above error I get in Chrome. If I try Edge I get the following error instead:

> SCRIPT5022: ReferenceError: 'fetch' is undefined

Because Edge doesn't support fetch yet.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend applying the following configuration to your Azure mobile service [found here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22201252/making-a-http-request-to-azure-mobile-services-from-asp-net-web-site)

```
   <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Alternatively, it could be a bug as discussed in this [post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870273/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-fr).

Comment: In Azure they migrated from Azure mobile services to Azure Mobile Apps, I'm using Azure Mobile Apps. And I added my domains to CORS option, now I added *, but it doesn't help, probably because CORS should be enabled on server part and https://accounts.google.com play this role now.